# php code is not working inside .html file

Tags: php, html, wordpress, .htaccess

I have added php code in html file and run this file as .html extension. For this technique i have added below code in .htaccess file.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

This whole folder is sub directory of wordpress project folder.When i am run this file in server, pop-up comes and my code file is opens in popup and it will give option to download. where i can see the whole code. What should i do to prevent to pop up box for download and run php code in html file and open as .html extension.

[image: I show it when i execute file.]

Can anyone help me what should i do?

Comment: is the `.htaccess` only present in the sub-folder? If so, you should place it in the root instead, so that way all `.html` files are/will be treated as php. Otherwise, you will get that popup each time.

Comment: so, can you answer my question please? ^ or did you leave the question?

Comment: .htaccess file is added in sub-directory.

Comment: someone gave you an answer; see that. However I'm not confident about that since we don't know what your code looks like, yet not having php tags shouldn't matter.

Comment: I feel that my first comment is the real solution here.

Comment: I have added that code in root .htaccess file also still i am facing same problem which i had.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use php in .html files, you must associate them with your PHP processor in your HTTP server's config file. In Apache, that looks like this:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html
```

Comment: i am using shared server. Should i put this code in .htaccess file?

Answer (score -2):

Your php block of codes must be inside the  tag

```html
<?php 
// Your php code might not work here
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php 
// Your php code will work here
 ?>
<head>
 <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
// Your php code will also work here
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and not having php tags shouldn't matter if there are no php directives.

Comment: @Fred PHP codes would not work if it is not situated inside the html tag. Happened to me so I assume he is experiencing the same mistake.

Comment: @JhanReyGonzales i have made .html file and i have add php code inside that file. and i have to execute html file. so your answer is not useful.

Comment: @BhaveshPatel what do you exactly mean by "php code not working"? Mind posting the the php code. Your php code might be not working in the first place.

Comment: @JhanReyGonzales I want to run php code inside html file.

Comment: @BhaveshPatel can you make a fiddle of your whole source code.

Comment: @YATO Its not php code so i can make a fiddle for that.. its html file which have php code. i hope you understood.